# Double integral (polar coordinates)

Tags: integration

Can anyone help me solve this using polar coordinates?
$$I=\iint_D \sqrt{xy} \mathrm dx\mathrm dy,$$ where  $$D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^{2}\mid (x^{2}+y^{2})^{2} \le xy\}$$

Comment: Why don't you do it your self ? You seem to know what are polar coordinates... the hardest part of the work is made ;)

Comment: and what is your problem exactly?

Comment: I can do it but i don't know how to choose the integration borders while integrating with theta. i would really appreciate the help.

Comment: The condition defining D means, in polar coordinates, that $\;r^2\le \cos\theta\sin\theta\;$ ...

Comment: @Masacroso The graph of the domain suggests that the theta must be between 0 to 90 degrees and 180 degrees to 270 degrees but i want to know if i could i have done this question without graphing calculator.

Comment: @DonAntonio yes thank you, and what about the constraints on theta?

Answer (score 2):

$x  =r\cos\theta\\y = r\sin\theta$

Jacobian:

$dx\ dy = r\ dr\ d\theta$

What are the limits of integration?

$r^4 \le r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta\\
|r|\le \sqrt{\cos\theta\sin\theta}$

There are no values $(x,y)$ in QII or  QIV that meet the criteria.  In those quadrants $xy<0$ while $(x^2+y^2)^2>0$

QIII will be symmetric to QI

$2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{\cos\theta\sin\theta}} r^2\sqrt {\cos\theta\sin\theta} \ dr\ d\theta$

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really helpful!!